# Problema ao chamar DLL em Python ctype windows

Tags: python, windows, dll

Estou com dificuldade em chamar uma dll em Python...
esta dando o seguinte erro: WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x026A65F0, as vezes funciona sem dar esse erro mais a maioria não funciona.
Estou utilizando assim:

```
from ctypes import *

dll = cdll.LoadLibrary(".dll")

dll.funcao.artypes = (c_char_p, c_char_p, c_char_p, c_char_p)

dll.funcao.restypes = c_int

dll.funcao(cast(Nome_Arq,c_char_p), 

cast(Entrada,c_char_p),cast(iv,c_char_p),cast(chave,c_char_p))
```

main.h

```
extern "C" DLL_EXPORT int funcao(char * Entrada, char * Saida, char* iv, char* chave);
```

main.cpp

```
extern "C" DLL_EXPORT int funcao(char * Entrada, char * Saida, char * iv_aux, char* chave_aux){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu diria que o problema está em como você está convertendo seus dados Python para passar para o C++ - Você não mostra como declara suas variáveis
`Entrada`, `iv` e `chave` - mas o `ctypes.cast` não converte uma string (ou outro objeto) Python para uma strinc compatível com C. Provavelmente o Cast simplesmente passa o endereço do objeto string do Python para o C - e a função C do outro lado vai tentar ler a string até encontrar um byte marcados com o valor `\x00` - as vezes encontra um no trecho de memória válido, e as vezes nao ( e nesses casos, você tem o erro acima) - mas de qualquer forma seu programa em C estará lendo lixo: bytes que nada tem a ver com os dados que você quer passar.

Para converter uma string de bytes (em Python 3, um objeto "bytes") para uma string C válida, basta chamar `ctypes.c_char_p` direto com a string. Isso fará uma cópia dos dados, e ainda acrescentará um marcador `\x00` ao final dos mesmos.

No seu código, a alteração é:

```
dll.funcao(c_char_p(Nome_Arq), c_char_p(Entrada), c_char_p(iv),c_char_p(chave))
```

Comment: Mesmo apos a alteração de passagem de para c_char_p(Entrada)... ocorreu o mesmo erro...